# Generic function to cache css property names

Tags: javascript, css

I created this object to get css property names according to the browser. 
e.g. js.transition will return either 'webkitTransition' or 'transition' as appropriate. All values are cached, ie. first reference will look up the value in the testElementStyle object, repeated references will return the cached value.

```
const js = {
    get testElementStyle() {
        delete this.testElementStyle;
        return this.testElementStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
    },
    get transition() {
        delete this.transition; 
        return this.transition = "transition" in this.testElementStyle ? "transition" : "webkitTransition" 
    },
    get transform() {
        delete this.transform; 
        return this.transform = "transform" in this.testElementStyle ? "transform" : "webkitTransform" 
    },
    get userSelect() { 
        delete this.userSelect 
        return this.userSelect = "userSelect" in this.testElementStyle ? "userSelect" : "webkitUserSelect" }    
}
```

As you can see the caching code is duplicated for each property. Ideally I want to create a single generic function that accepts prop name and does the rest.

e.g.

```
const cache = prop => alt => {
    delete this[prop];
    return this[prop] = prop in this.testElementStyle ? prop : alt;
}
```

... which of course does not work, I'm kinda stuck, help please!

---

This is what I did in the interim before reading your comments. With your tips I can now take it to the next level. Thanks everyone!

```
const testElementStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
function cache(prop, alt) {
    delete this[prop];
    return this[prop] = prop in testElementStyle ? prop : alt;
}
const js = {
    get transition() { return cache.call(this, "transition", "webkitTransition") },
    get transform() { return cache.call(this, "transform", "webkitTransform") },
    get userSelect() { return cache.call(this, "userSelect", "webkitUserSelect") },
}
const css = {
    get transform() { return cache.call(this, "transform", "-webkit-transform") },
}
```

Comment: The overhead of creating an element is relatively small; what really should be cached is the result of checks.

Comment: Does your current code work? Just playing around, it looks like *all* of the `in` operators in your question will return `true` unless the property gets manually `delete`d - they look to contain the empty string by default, you may have to change your check to `!== ''`. Look at `document.createElement('div').style.transform`

Comment: Code works where I have used it but you got me thinking maybe it won't when i test in other browsers

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone

Comment: In both FF 56 and Chrome 70, the returned properties appear to be the empty string - in other words, they *are* properties on the object, they just don't hold anything meaningful

Comment: @CertainPerformance. The intention of the code is to check the presence of the property name, not get the value. Have to look at it again

Comment: Problem is that the `.style` object looks like it will already have those properties by default, even if you've never explicitly assigned anything to it before, so the `prop in testElementStyle` will *always* evaluate to `true` for a property that the style object can have.

Comment: @CertainPerformance. So a webkit browser will have both style.transition and style.webkitTransition?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Thanks for the clarification for the `delete` operation. I didn't think it was necessary but MDN used it in their [lazy getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Smart_self-overwriting_lazy_getters) docs

Comment: @myleftshoe - Sorry, they're right. I missed that you were deleting a getter.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a `Proxy`, which can detect the property string you're trying to access on the object and perform custom actions depending on that string. With that string, you can then check to see if it exists in the `style`, use bracket notation to assign it to the object, and concatenate with `webkit`:

```
const js = new Proxy({}, {
  get: (obj, prop) => {
    if (prop === 'testElementStyle') {
      obj.testElementStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
      return this.testElementStyle;
    }
    this[prop] = prop in obj.testElementStyle
      ? prop
      : 'webkit' + prop.replace(/^./, char => char.toUpperCase());
    return this[prop];
  }
});
```

Comment: Why create an array just to use `includes`? Either use `hasOwnProperty` or `in` like the OP did.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder we could have also just checked `obj.testElementStyle[prop]`.. why `prop in obj.testElementStyle`?

Comment: @Mr_Green - That would fail if the property's value were falsy (for instance: `""`).

Comment: Actually, I think the way going forward is to get comfortable with [Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect), since it aligns with other languages' conventions.  So another recommended alternative might be `Reflect.has(obj,'testElementStyle')`

Comment: @vol7ron. My head´s starting to hurt now. More, options, more that I don´t know, more learning I guess!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Use a function and pass in a string
2. Use a `Proxy` (ES2015+)

As [CertainPerformance has Proxy covered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53079781/157247), here's how you'd do it with a function:

```
const js = {
    get testElementStyle() {
        return this.testElementStyle = document.createElement('div').style;
    },
    get(name) {
        return this[name] = name in this.testElementStyle ? name : "webkit" + name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
js.testElementStyle(); // It's unclear to me why you make this setup call necessary
const transform = js.get("transform");
```